# IOS Multiple Developer Certificates per One Login / One Apple ID / One Development Machine

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

In the current xcode organizer there is Library / Developer Profile.  Currently I have a personal developer profile which I would like to keep.

The company that I am working for has their own developer profile that I would also like to use.  I have to request a certificate from them.  To do this one goes to the Web Site Developer Porthole and usually this is blank and then there is a request button.  But when there is one present, there is no button to request.

http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/index.action

How do I get the request to the company for the other certificate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must first be invited to join your company's development team. After accepting the invitation, you'll be prompted to choose a development team whenever you log into developer.apple.com.

So, first create a certificate signing request using Keychain Access, then log into the developer site and choose the company team. Then you can enter the portal and request a certificate. If I remember correctly, you'll then be prompted to upload your certificate signing request.

Comment: Ok, where exactly to choose company team.  Just want to make sure we get the correct order.  1) Get Invite, 2) Create Cert, 3) Choose Company Team, 4) Request a Cert, 5) Team Approves  Can't seem to Request A Cert, did not have to have invite for other developer that did not have a personal cert.  That order was 1) Create Cert, 2) No Crests on Web site, request button appears, Request a Cert,  3) Team Approves